# Ошибка при установке Bitrix на хосинг

Tags: php, битрикс

При установке Bitrix на хостинг появляется следующая ошибка:
Для установки продукта в кодировке UTF-8 необходимо установить библиотеку mbstring c параметрами mbstring.func_overload больше 2, mbstring.internal_encoding=UTF-8.
Как исправить? Apache 2.4.10, php 5.5.31

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данные параметры нужно установить в php.ini.

```
mbstring.func_overload = 2
mbstring.internal_encoding=UTF-8
```

Если же у вас не выделенный сервер, то напишите в тех поддержку хостинга - они должны установить.

Answer (score 0):

> mbstring.func_overload = 2
>   mbstring.internal_encoding=UTF-8

можно и в .htaccess прописать